# installing additional eclipse indigo files

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-indigo

After downloading Eclipse Indigo  on a clean pc, when I try to download from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7  and download SDKs and Google Plugin , at about 35% of the way through I start getting errors.

```
Install download1
An internal error occurred during: "Install download1".
Comparison method violates its general contract!

Install download2
An internal error occurred during: "Install download1".
Comparison method violates its general contract!

Install download3
An internal error occurred during: "Install download1".
Comparison method violates its general contract!

Installing Software
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/erice/Downloads/eclipse-jee-indigo-win32-x86_64/eclipse/.
C:\Users\erice\Downloads\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\com.ning.async-http-client_1.6.3.201112281337.jar (Access is denied)
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/erice/Downloads/eclipse-jee-indigo-win32-x86_64/eclipse/.
C:\Users\erice\Downloads\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\com.ning.async-http-client_1.6.3.201112281337.jar (Access is denied)
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.0.200.20111228-1245
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.0.200.20111228-1245
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.0.200.20111228-1245
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.netty,3.2.4.Final-201112281337
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known issue of Eclipse 3.7 running on Java 7.

Possible workarounds:

- use JRE7u5 (last version)
- when using JRE7, theres a small rarely documented feature
  set system property java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
  This should use old implementation and should not bring up the bug
  (I haven't tested, but you can search for the property ;-) )

See [bug 317785](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317785) for detail.

Comment: I downgraded to Java 6 JRE and everything works installing except for the Android stuff.  What gives?                                                                  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.  Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android...
  Missing requirement: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android requires 'bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 12.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android...

Comment: It's when I check to download Google App Engine and GWT Designer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run eclipse with older java version. Start Eclipse from command line with:

> D:\Eclipse\eclipse j2ee indigo>eclipse -vm C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe

It worked for me.

(-vm is pointing to your jre instalation. Remember: Eclipse does not use JAVA_HOME variable. it uses its own Java.)

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of downgrading to Java 6 JRE and downloading ADT for the App Engine downloading problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Could not install Android Native Development Tools. Was getting this error - "An internal error occurred during: "Install download3".Comparison method violates its general contract! "

I ended up installing CDT (C/C++ Development Tools) from the Helios update site. Then I could install Android Native Development Tools.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem during installation of BIRT plugin into Eclipse Indigo. I solved it by [using this URL](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.2/) in the Update Manager. I had to add the URL first, because only [this URL](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/3.7/) was there.